# How to create a C macro for appending /n to every printf

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, printf

`MY_PRINT` is a macro throughout the code, which just does printf.
I want to temporarily modify it to also append \n after every printf.

However, when I do this:

```
#define SENS_PRINT(x)        printf(x);   printf("\n")
MY_PRINT( "\n   #%d:  %c    ", ++command_line_number, sensor_operation_code );
```

...the output is trash:   `#3405240:   <alpha symbol>`

This prints ok, but no \n at end:

```
#define SENS_PRINT   printf
```

Comment: Thing is, printf takes a variable number of arguments, which you're not taking into account when you use (x) so I don't think that scheme is going to work

Comment: Just a call for common sense: what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve with `#define MY_PRINT printf` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your macro to be able to take various arguments, just like the real printf. You can do this with variadic macros.

There's also a danger that two separate expressions aren't interpreted as the macro suggests when the macro is the only expression in a conditional code block. Think about what the macro does if you say `if (flag) SENS_PRINT(...);`. One way to prevent this is to wrap the macro in a `do { ... } while(0)` block.

A variadic macro that appends a newline to `printf` could look like this:

```
#define PRINTFLN(...) do { printf(__VA_ARGS__); puts(""); } while (0)
```

You can use it just like `printf`:

```
PRINTFLN("Hello %s!", "cruel world");
if (flag) PRINTFLN("%d + %d == %d", x, y, sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

The C language lets you concatenate string literals separated by whitespace. Provided all of your calls to `MY_PRINT` use a string literal as their formatting argument, you can define a variadic macro which will directly append `"\n"` to your format string, and then apply the rest of your arguments.

Defining your macro like so

```
#define MY_PRINT(format, ...) printf(format "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

you will be able to directly append a newline to the formatting argument.

Using this method only one function call will be performed, but any call formatted using anything other than a string literal will cause a compile error.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that if you call it with a format string only, like `MY_PRINT("string that doesn't have any arguments")` it will fail since __VA_ARGS__ will expand to a `,` causing a syntax error (on confirming platforms).

Comment: @BeeOnRope works fine for me using MSVC and windows. No syntax error

Comment: Different compilers could handle it differently. In GNU CPP it reports error. A token paste operator will fix this.
`#define MY_PRINT(format, ...) printf(format "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)`
Reference to [Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_3.html#SEC19) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with function-line macros is that the preprocess treats all comma-separated arguments as arguments to the macro and not as a single argument. So your compiler should really have complained that you pass to many arguments to the macro.

A simple solution is to enclose the macro argument in parentheses:

```
MY_PRINT( ( "\n   #%d:  %c    ", ++command_line_number, sensor_operation_code ) );
//        ^                                                                   ^
//        |                                                                   |
// Note extra parentheses here...                                      and here
```

Another solution is to use [variadic macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx).

---

On a somewhat related note, your macro, as you show it, can't be used in construct like e.g.

```
if (some_condition)
    MY_PRINT(...);
```

That will be replaced like

```
if (some_condition)
    printf(...);
printf(...);
```

If you have multiple statements inside a macro, you need to enclose it in a block, like e.g.

```
#define MY_PRINTF(...) \
    do {               \
        statement1;    \
        statement2;    \
        .              \
        .              \
        .              \
        statementN;    \
    } while (0)
```